# ASP .Net Update individual element on asp page on textchanged postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have two gridviews in a webform visual studio project. The first is a fixed size grid which, using javascript, I have managed to set up to return a grid reference which is then output to two textboxes. These textboxes then update a second grid with records that relate to the number in the clicked cell of the first grid:

[image: Progress Grid Ok]

The first gridview is the colourful one, the second gridview is the dash separated text below it. In the example you can see the selected cell references are D and 3a and the second grid below is showing the 6 students' names the number in the cell D 3a is referring to. This works great. However, after I click on the grid more than once the layout gets messed up:

[image: Progress Grid Not Ok]

As you can see the rendered headers disappear and this then cause issues with the layout and subsequently the grid reference positioning.

In the databound event for the first gridview I have the following vbcode that generates the additional headers on the gridview which disappear:

```
    If gvProgressGrid IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim row As New GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal)

        Dim left As TableCell = New TableHeaderCell()
        left.ColumnSpan = 2
        row.Cells.Add(left)
        left.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None

        Dim grades As TableCell = New TableHeaderCell()
        grades.ColumnSpan = 10
        grades.Text = "Grades"
        row.Cells.Add(grades)

        Dim cohort As TableCell = New TableHeaderCell()
        cohort.ColumnSpan = 1
        cohort.Text = "Cohort"
        cohort.RowSpan = 2
        cohort.BackColor = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(242, 242, 242)
        row.Cells.Add(cohort)

        Dim expected As TableCell = New TableHeaderCell()
        expected.ColumnSpan = 2

        Select Case strYear
            Case "11"
                expected.Text = "Students achieving expected progress (3 or more levels)"
            Case "10"
                expected.Text = "Students achieving expected progress (2 or more levels)"
            Case "9"
                expected.Text = "Students achieving expected progress (1 or more levels)"
        End Select

        expected.BackColor = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(216, 216, 216)
        expected.Width = 250
        row.Cells.Add(expected)

        Dim above As TableCell = New TableHeaderCell()
        above.ColumnSpan = 2
        Select Case strYear
            Case "11"
                above.Text = "Students achieving above expected progress (4 or more levels)"
            Case "10"
                above.Text = "Students achieving above expected progress (3 or more levels)"
            Case "9"
                above.Text = "Students achieving above expected progress (2 or more levels)"
        End Select
        above.BackColor = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(242, 242, 242)
        above.Width = 250
        row.Cells.Add(above)

        Dim t As Table = TryCast(gvProgressGrid.Controls(0), Table)
        If t IsNot Nothing Then
            t.Rows.AddAt(0, row)
        End If
    End If
```

I automatically trigger a change of text/loss of focus on the second textbox using the following code in my javascript (the script that grabs the grid reference of the first gridview on click):

```
document.getElementById("<%=tbKS2.ClientID%>").value = strKS2;
__doPostBack(document.getElementById("<%=tbKS2.ClientID%>").name, '')
```

It's only the second gridview that needs to update when the first grid is clicked and it appears as though the whole page or at the very least the first gridview is updating too.

How can I get it so that once the above textbox postback is triggered only my second gridview is updated and the rest of the elements on the page stay rendered how they are?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried running the code in Page_prerender event instead of itemdatabound?

Comment: @ajakblackgoat thanks for taking a look. Yes I moved the code to the prerender, but then it thows an error: argumentoutofrange was unhandled by user code whe delcaring the table variable: Dim t As Table = TryCast(gvProgressGrid.Controls(0), Table)

Comment: that means at that point, your gvProgressGrid does not have any controls yet. So Controls(0) throws that exception.

Comment: @ajakblackgoat cool, so should I binding the gridview earlier than that in the pageload?

Comment: just a thought, i think your added row and cells are not persisted across postback. i'm still testing with it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to insert the row during **RowCreated** event of the grid:

```
Private Sub gvProgressGrid_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvProgressGrid.RowCreated
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then

        ' the rest of your code
        ' ...
        ' ...


    End If

End Sub
```